# Best way to define status field in database tables

Tags: model, database

I find that status fields are defined in 2 ways.

1. `int/smallint/tinyint` : each value represent some status
2. `varchar` : We save status text in databse directly. In general practice Models are defined with CONTANTS for statuses which are responsible for bringing up text.

What is best way among these in what kind of conditions or is there any other way that I dont know?

And why in Magento we never use enum data type, which is oftenly used in other systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have tried to explain it in detail here. Please go through it

The int data type is the primary integer data type in SQL Server. The bigint data type is intended for use when integer values might exceed the range that is supported by the int data type.

bigint fits between smallmoney and int in the data type precedence chart.

Functions return bigint only if the parameter expression is a bigint data type. SQL Server does not automatically promote other integer data types (tinyint, smallint, and int) to bigint.

**Why in Magento enum is not preferred:**

**Data isn't being treated like data.**

Male/Female, Mr/Mrs/Ms, Africa/Asia/etc: these bits of text that people use ENUM columns for are data. When you use an ENUM column, you're technically moving data from where it belongs (in actual database fields), to somewhere it doesn't (into the database metadata, specifically a column definition). This is different than putting constraints on the data, which is what we are doing when we say that a numeric column can only hold an integer, or that a date column can't be null - that's fine and quite necessary. With an ENUM we're actually storing pieces of data in a place that was only intended to hold crucial information about the model. In short, an ENUM column violates the rules of normalization.

**Changing the member list of ENUM columns is very expensive.**

Invariably, what happens is this: you create an ENUM column and say "no way NEVER will this list change or need added to". But humans are really poor at estimating the entire scope of something, and even worse at predicting the future. R&D dreams up a whole new product type. Your company adds another shipping method. North America crashes into Asia.

**It's impossible to add additional attributes or related info.**

And the backbone of magento is attributes as it follows EAV

**ENUM columns may only offer limited or negligible effects on optimization.**

The usual justifications for using ENUM, are centered around optimization, in the conventional sense of performance gains, and sometimes in the sense of simplifying a complicated model to be more comprehensible.

**You can't reuse the member-list of an ENUM column in other tables.**

For more info please read the article below::
http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-enum-vs-integer-types

Comment: Thanks SoftProdigy. Great answer regarding enum data type. Could you explain first half of my question also I need some understanding to decide what way is better and when.

Comment: Hello Deependra. It is INT, because the magento structure supports it that way. And it is advised to follow magento conventions while working on magento applications

Comment: OMGGG I am triggered that you used Male/Female as an example for an ENUM column!  Gender is an infinite continuum that can't be expressed as an ENUM! It can only be expressed as a double precision floating point number!!!!